# Regex to find phrase not in a list

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to find a RegEx that will find a phrase that is not in a list of specific phrases.

I have a list of labels and I want to find out if there are any other labels not in a list I supply to the RegEx.

For example:

```
label1: value 

label2: value

label3: value

newlabel: value
```

I want to be able to specify that label 1-3 should be there, but only capture newlabel as it's not in the list. I only know the names of the labels I am expecting, not the ones that I'm not expecting.

Any help is appreciated.

Something similar to

```
Dim match As Match = regex.Match([anything containing a colon :] except label1|label2|label3)
```

Comment: what language are you using, and do you have something to share that you have attempted?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for. Can you post example sentences and their positive and negative results (examples of output and non-output)? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks, the input is what I added to the question. The output would be passing a regex test for the expression.
I don't have an example of what I've tried already as I have no idea how to start this one. I am using the .Net version

Comment: Can you collect all labels and remove all matched to your list?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need: `^(?!label[1-3])([[:alnum:]]+):\s*(.*)$`. The first capture group is the label and second is the value

Comment: Are these strings standalone? Or is that a multiline string? If you are just looking to extract any single words before `:` but the ones on the list, you  may use [`\b(\w+):(?<!\b(?:label1|label2|label3):)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%5cw%2b%29%3a%28%3f%3c!%5cb%28%3f%3alabel1%7clabel2%7clabel3%29%3a%29&i=label1%3a+value+%0d%0a%0d%0alabel2%3a+value%0d%0a%0d%0alabel3%3a+value%0d%0a%0d%0anewlabel%3a+value) and grab all `match.Groups(1).Value`s.

Comment: So, what is the expected output and why?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I tried your example last night and it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"\b(\w+):(?<!\b(?:label1|label2|label3):)"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%5Cw%2B%29%3A%28%3F%3C!%5Cb%28%3F%3Alabel1%7Clabel2%7Clabel3%29%3A%29&i=label1%3A%20value%20%0D%0A%0D%0Alabel2%3A%20value%0D%0A%0D%0Alabel3%3A%20value%0D%0A%0D%0Anewlabel%3A%20value).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 - one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `(?<!\b(?:label1|label2|label3):)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is `label1`, `label2` or `label3` as whole words (since they are preceded with a word boundary) and followed with a colon.

In VB.NET code, use `Regex.Matches` to get the *MatchCollection* containing the *Match* objects, and then get `.Groups(1).Value` of each match.

Comment: I noticed this only works if the "labels" are all the same length.
Is there a version that works for variable length labels?

Comment: @BirdLaw Are you using it in Python? Note it is a .NET regex.

Comment: I'm just using regex101.com

Comment: @BirdLaw Then you are not doing the right thing: regex101 does not support  .NET regex. Use http://regexhero.net/tester or http://regexstorm.net/tester.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about .NET, so I don't think this answers the question fully

Comment: @BirdLaw Do you not see `.net` tag? If you have a new question, make sure it has not been asked, and ask.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the tag